# How can I sort by date the result of this multiple parsing file script?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have files from different systems I have parsed both files using the following code:
The output is for example the following:

```
server1_audit.log
server1_audit.log:  ['2019-09-14', '03:03:55,613', 'started', 'container']
server1_audit.log:  ['2019-09-22', '02:34:29,249', 'started', 'container']
server2_audit.log
server2_audit.log:  ['2018-11-19', '02:37:45,351', 'started', 'container']
server2_audit.log:  ['2018-11-19', '03:58:52,228', 'started', 'container']
```

How can I sort this result without having to use MSExcel. to get the final result of:

```
server2_audit.log:  ['2018-11-19',  '02:37:45,351', 'started',  'container']
server2_audit.log:  ['2018-11-19',  '03:58:52,228', 'started',  'container']
server1_audit.log:  ['2019-09-14',  '03:03:55,613', 'started',  'container']
server1_audit.log:  ['2019-09-22',  '02:34:29,249', 'started',  'container']
```

```
import os.path

file_location = os.path.join('folder', 'logs', '*.log')
print(file_location)

import glob
filenames = glob.glob(file_location)
print(filenames)


for f in filenames:
    file_name = os.path.basename(f)
    print(file_name)
    outfile = open(f,'r')
    data = outfile.readlines()
    outfile.close()
    for line in data:
        if 'started container' in line:
            words = line.split()
            print(f"{file_name}:  {words}")
```

Comment: Hello. Could you give the current result and the expected one ?

Comment: Do you want to sort based on the following:  (1) descending on file_name and (2) ascending on words[0] ?